# Uniform bound on sequence of piecewise constant functions; improving the convergence of the sum.

Tags: functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, lp-spaces

Let $f_n\colon (0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that
$$\lVert f_n \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T)} \leq C$$
for all $n$, i.e. they are uniformly bounded. Furthermore,
$$f_n(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{jn}\chi_{I_{jn}}(t)$$
where $a_{jn} \in \mathbb{R}$ and for each $n$, $\{I_{jn}\}_j$ is a partition of $(0,T)$ into $n$ subintervals with measure $T/n$ (i.e., it is a uniform partition).

By taking the $L^p$ norm for any $p < \infty$,

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac 1n|a_{jn}|^p \leq C$$
holds uniformly in $n$. My question is, can this be improved by having

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n^\alpha}|a_{jn}|^p \leq C$$
for some $\alpha <1$ and some $p \geq 1$, again with $C$ independent of $n$?

Comment: What if all $a_{j,n}$ are equal to 1?

Comment: @PhoemueX then not even the penultimate displayed inequality holds, right?

Comment: Of course it does. $1^p=1$.

Comment: Oops sorry, I was getting confused with thinking it would be the harmonic series but we are not summing over $n$.